# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I have 3 Models in My Laravel App like Employee , Salary and Title. Employee Model one to Many Relationship with both Salary and Title Models. Now I need update data using EmployeeController updateEmployee function. using this function I need update some time all 3 tables tada some time one or two tables data according to users update needs.
EmployeeController

```
public function updateEmployee(Request $request, $id)
{
    $employee = Employee::find($id);

    if (is_null($employee)) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Employee not found'], 404);
    }

    // Update employee information
    $employee->update([
        'first_name' => $request->input('first_name')
       ]);

    // Update related titles
    $employee->titles->update([
        'title' => $request->input('title')
       ]);

    // Update related salaries
    $employee->salaries->update([
        'salary' => $request->input('salary')
       ]);
return response($employee, 200);
}
```

and my api route is following

```
Route::put('updateEmployee/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\EmployeeController@updateEmployee');
```

Employee Model

```
public function titles(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Title::class, 'emp_no');
}

public function salaries(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Salary::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Salary Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

Title Model

```
public function employee(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class, 'emp_no');
}
```

but when I try update using postman Employee and Salary Models data I got following error message

> BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist. in file F:\2023\code\2023\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Macroable\Traits\Macroable.php on line 113

what is wrong with this? how could I fix this problem here?

Comment: `$employee->titles` is a `Collection`, which **doesn't** have an `update()` method. `$employee->titles()` is a `Builder` instance (from the defined Relationship) and **does** have an `update()` method. Please be aware of the difference and code accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling update on collection but it should be called on relation instance instead

use `titles()` instead of `titles`:

```php
    // Update related titles
    $employee->titles()->update([
        'title' => $request->input('title')
       ]);

    // Update related salaries
    $employee->salaries()->update([
        'salary' => $request->input('salary')
       ]);
```

Comment: it is sucess here. but one more problem exit that is if I try to update only two models then occured following error message `Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column &#039;title&#039; cannot be null (SQL: update `titles` set `title` = ? where `titles`.`emp_no` = 10 and `titles`.`emp_no` is not null) in file F:\2023\code\2023\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 760`

Comment: Well, it's clear and loud, you have to check if your `$request->input('title')` is empty or not.. you have better do some validation before any interaction with database , Validation Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation